# Rails_admin gem export functionality overriding options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-admin

Export functionality override & using sidekiq processing the data.

Comment: Could you reformulate it as a question?

Comment: Hi  Guillermo Siliceo Trueba,  We are using rails_admin gem in that most of the model's data exceeded 40k records due to this we are not able to do the export action. Export action will be kept on running  but the file won't be downloaded.

Comment: Is there any gem option that we can use. so that we export any number of records.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, there's not built-in in rails admin. You'd have to copy the export action to your repo, require it, and modify the code to work the way you want. Take a look at it here https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/export.rb